# Is there a layout view in Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, printing

Is there a layout view in Quantum GIS (something similar to ArcGis layout view) ?

Anyway I am looking for tutorial or some good practices how i can prepare a nice map to print in Quantum GIS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tool is called "Print Composer" and it should be covered in the manual.

You might find further information in the answers to [Obtaining print quality PDF or PNG output from QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-do-i-get-the-best-print-quality-from-qgis-and-is-arc-better)

Comment: Once you've got something looking pretty good in the print composer you can save as SVG and do final editing, fancy typography etc, using something like Inkscape (or Adobe Illustrator if you have the cash).

Answer (score 5):

Print Composer is a great tool as @underdark mentioned; however, bare in mind that it's not as sophisticated as Arc's tool, especially when it comes to labeling and general options.

It's usability is awkward, for example, if you right click on an object instead of it opening a context menu, it locks the object. so if you want to put objects behind or in front of each other, you have to click on the item, then go to the menu and click send/to/back or front

In a legend for instance, you can't split it into multiple columns.

IF you resize an item, there is no option to rescale contents, rather it just makes the box bigger.

I've always felt that the composer and the lack of advanced labeling methods in qgis are its biggest drawbacks. Of course those drawbacks are offsett-ed by the amazing speed and functionality of the software.

I'd like to note that the idea of composer in QGIS, from my understanding and as mentioned to me on the irc log, is not to be a "photoshop replacement" rather it's more of a tool to get you going and take ti to a graphics based program to do the editing.

Answer (score 2):

http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/06/making-maps-for-print-using-qgis.html
The tutorial in the link demonstrates how to create layout with pictures. It is easy, follow the steps given in the tutorial. Print composer is the tool used in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the actual size of the map, and not just the box around it, you want to play with the scale in the map section. It's kind of weird, but this is the only way I found I could make my map bigger, and not just increase the box.

Comment: The mouse wheel is used to zoom.