# What free software can be used for print-quality map production?

Tags: cartography, printing, software-recommendations, free-software

I am creating art prints using spatial data.

I use ESRI software every day for my regular job, therefore I am proficient in GIS. However, I can't afford ESRI software for my art projects at home.

Currently I am using QGIS. What are some recommended products for producing print-quality maps?

Comment: You should give a try to Mapnik with TileMill or Mapbox Studio

Comment: Just FYI, as long as you are not using it for commercial purposes, you can get ArcGIS Desktop for $100/year: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home

Comment: QGIS allows you to style geographic data and export print-quality graphics (PDF, PNG, etc) at your desired resolution/size using print composer. If you need to do anything else I'd suggest using Inkscape. This workflow mimics what cartographers do using ArcMap and Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: How do we get this interesting and useful thing opened up again? Something about community...?

Comment: @martinf I have edited the question to hopefully be less subjective, and requested it be reopened and made community wiki.

Comment: Related: [How do I get the best print quality from QGIS (and is Arc better)?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9784)

Answer (score 2):

You should give [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) with [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) or [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/#win64) a try.

[image][image][image][image]