# Is it possible to mimic ArcPublisher with PDF or similar?

Tags: qgis, pdf, open-source-gis, arcgis-publisher

I want to provide mapping output in a format that mimics the delivery provided by ArcPublisher and wonder if anybody has any experience in this.

For instance, the PDF format now supports layers which can turned on and off, but can QGIS or GDAL export in such a way to enable this to happen rather than a basic PDF?

Alternatively, perhaps there is another FOSS product which can provide a similar export.  I want to avoid the client having to download and install software if at all possible (I am assuming that they will have a PDF viewer available).

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite implemented yet - would be a good feature enhancement for QGIS.

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code_2010#SVG.2FPDF_export_improvements

from 
[Can QGIS preserve layers when exporting to PDF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7078/can-qgis-preserve-layers-when-exporting-to-pdf)

Comment: Ah! How frustrating - so near and yet so far!  I'm looking for alternatives too so I guess this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: IIRC, viewing the maps produced by Arcpublisher requires having an ArcReader installed on the client machine, and she also needs access to the data layers. To "mimic" that workflow, why not just install QGIS on your clients, and have the data layers accessible. Then you need only distribute a QGIS project, and clients will be able to turn layers on and off (and much more). The basic functionality of QGIS is certainly no harder than ArcReader.

Comment: Theoretically a good plan but the client doesn't want to install any new software and already has ArcReader.  They have one of those locked-down systems that prevent the user from installing anything without filling in a form in triplicate, obtaining a dispensation from the Pope first and giving six months notice to their IT department.  I've worked in a couple of places like that and it is a monumental pain so I appreciate their desire to avoid new installations.