# Layered PDF from QGIS - Layers can't be turned on/off

Tags: qgis, layers, pdf, svg, scribus

I was following [this guide](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/A-short-guide-on-producing-a-multi-layered-pdf-from-Qgis-td5193279.html) on producing a layered PDF from QGIS, but somewhere along the way I seem to miss something. Exporting layers via the composer into a svg works fine, also loading the svg into scribus, splitting the groups and shifting the polygons to a new layer works.

The [exported PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lum104b1jh8aryp/layer_pdf_test03.pdf?dl=0) even contains layers, but these don't disappear when being turned off.
For reasons of reproducibility, here is also [the scribus file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kud4yck732yv64l/layer_pdf_test03.sla?dl=0).

Perhaps my question should be attached to [Can QGIS preserve layers when exporting to PDF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7078) from 2015.

Trying this under Win7, using QGis 2.18.11, Scribus 1.5.2 and Acrobat Reader XI.

Comment: seems to be a bug in scribus: https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=14978

Comment: With QGIS 3.10 this question is outdated.

Comment: if it now works, can you please also comment in the ticket in the scirbus bugtracker?

Comment: @a.l.e Sorry, the question is outdated so far, that QGIS itself can produce layered PDF using the latest LTR. Whether the bug in Scribus is gone or not, I don't know.

Comment: ok, thanks for the information.