# Export a layered pdf using GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, geospatial-pdf

### How to use GDAL to export a layered pdf from the map canvas?

I want to export a layered pdf from QGIS. In response to a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273650/export-a-layered-pdf-in-qgis-3-0), I received an answer which implies that it's possible to export a layered pdf from map canvas. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how. I followed the links provided, and read all the information. I still don't understand.
This is the answer:

> This exact feature has not be implemented yet for the composer. However, you can export layered pdf from the canvas. You might want to follow the feature request as you will find some tips on the subject : https://issues.qgis.org/issues/9362
>
> See for example :
>
> As GDAL 1.10 supports GeoPDF (See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html), one can export a PDF with layers (a raster layer and a polyline vector layer) from Processing inserting a OGR_DATASOURCE parameter in the "Additional creation parameters" box to add the vector layer. However, it only exports vectors without style.
>
> ...You can also be a sponsor to have this feature developed ! ;)

This answer has only led me to more questions:

- Where is "processing"? Is it the processing menu, or the processing
  toolbox?
- In the processing toolbox, I see GDAL/OGR [48 geoalgorithms]. None of
  the geoalgorithms seem to have anything to do with exporting a pdf. Should I be using one of these geoalgorithms? If so, which one?
- Where is the "Additional creation parameter" box?