# QGIS Map Viewer for co-workers

Tags: qgis

I am trying to find a program or application that would allow co-workers to view maps and various layers produced with QGIS but not have the ability to alter or modify the data.  It would be nice to produce something more interactive than just sharing a PDF map, any suggestions of a way to proceed??

Comment: Could you make and share a web map? http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

Comment: Layered PDFs are a possible solution, but a work-intensive one, and also one currently not available for QGis.

Comment: There's a workaround for producing a layered PDF from QGIS, although I've personally never gotten it to work: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7078/81764

Comment: How about using [QGIS Browser](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/qgis_browser/qgis_browser.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your network environment you could place the data in a folder that has read only permissions for those users and then add the data from that folder to QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish you map(s) on [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/) and give permalink to web-map (explore web-map via browser) or create WMS service (explore map via QGIS, ArcGIS, MapInfo, etc.).

See documentation about [publish map using NextGIS Connect plugin](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html#ngcom-ngqgis-connect-data-upload), [explore web-map](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/webmaps_client.html#ngw-webmaps-client) and [create WMS service](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/layers.html#wms-service).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customise QGIS, so you can remove certain toolbars and menus very easily.

Check out:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#customization

So while it would not make the data read only, it would remove all of the tools to edit the data. This in turn also makes it easier for the colleagues to use QGIS as it is a bit simpler.