# Export layers to PDF

Tags: qgis, layers

I have created a layer and using the category option have created lots of 'sub layers' is there a way to convert these to real layers so I can export each layer to a PDF?

[image: Sub Layer]

Comment: Thanks and other words of appreciation should not be included in your questions and answers - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts0.

Comment: Sounds your answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212483/67659

Comment: The answer that @ArashMad proposes involves the use of the QGIS *Composer*, now known as the *Print Layout*. However, it looks like your screenshot was instead taken from the Project's Table of Contents. It would help if you could define "sub layers". From your screenshot, it appears that you have one layer, symbolized on a field with values 0, 1, 2, and you'd like to export each of those values as separate layers.  If that's the case, maybe you could edit your post to state that.  Anyway, welcome to SE GIS, David!  Your participation is appreciated.  Thanks!  ;)